# How NHibernate updates newly inserted ID in Entity?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Consider code below: -

```
public T Save<T>(T instance) where T : class
{
    using(ISession.BeginTransaction())
    {
        ISession.Save(instance);
        ISession.Transaction.Commit();
        ISession.Refresh(instance);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

How `NHibernate` fills up `ID` property with newly generated `ID` irrespective of database and datatype? Initially, I thought it must be using similar way we do it manually like `@@Identity`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` for MS SQL Server and relative query for other databases. But this does not work with all data types like `GUID`.

When I call `ISession.Refresh(instance);`, I get newly inserted id in `instance` object. This is not a problem, just want to understand how `NHibernate` does this.

Comment: It depends on the id generator. Each generator will do it differently (https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Id). For example, if you dig into `MsSql2000Dialect`, you'll find this line: `return "select SCOPE_IDENTITY()";`. Regardless of generation, you shouldn't need to refresh the object to be able to get its id.

Comment: Thanks @A_J. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the id generator. Each [generator](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Id) will do it differently.

For example, if you dig into MsSql2000Dialect, you'll find this line:

```
return "select SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

Regardless of generation, you shouldn't need to refresh the object to be able to get its id.

Therefore, this code:

```
using(ISession.BeginTransaction())
{
    ISession.Save(instance);
    ISession.Transaction.Commit();
    ISession.Refresh(instance);
    return instance;
}
```

could become:

```
using(ISession.BeginTransaction())
{
    ISession.Save(instance);
    ISession.Transaction.Commit();

    return instance;
}
```

and `instance` will have an id that's not equal to its `unsaved-value`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for?

You define exactly how you want the ID to working in your mappings. It is not irrespective to the datatype or database.  For example, you can't have an identity generator with Oracle or a GuidComb for a non-Guid ID.

Here's an example using mapping by code

```
        Id(x => x.Id, map =>
        {
            map.Column("Id");
            map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });
```

See the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html) with section 5.1.5.1. generator

Comment: SQL Server introduced sequences in SQL Server 2012, the earliest supported edition